# Recent media not updated in VLC when opening file from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, vlc

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> from within VLC to play a file, it will save the file to the list displayed in the *Open Recent Media* menu.

[image: vlc Open recent media]

But when adding file to VLC via Nautilus it does not get added to *Open Recent Media*. Is there a way to add from Nautilus to VLC?

[image]

Or is this a bug (feature) that I should report to VLC?

Comment: Since this could be considered a missing feature instead of a bug and there may be a workaround, I don't think we should rush to close this question just yet. ([Bug *reports* are considered off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), as you're probably aware. Feature requests are too, but in general asking *how* to do something, which you're doing here, is within the scope of this site.) With that said, I do recommend [filing a bug / feature request for this on Launchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if I am doing something wrong. Install a package or something? Like you should I probably should file a bug report.

Comment: _"adding file to vlc via nautilus"_ like drag n drop?! if so just informing that it gets recorded in the play history in mine!

Comment: @hash no drag and drop. I have made VLC my default player. just clicking it will open the file. No recent media!

Comment: I guess it is not possible??